# Remove up to a character and insert space

Tags: vim

Given I have text such as:

(* is cursor position)

`let(:study) { FactoryBot.create :study*, site: site }`

And I want

`let(:study) { FactoryBot.create :study }`

At the moment I do `ct}`, press space and hit escape.

I wonder if there is a better way to delete to a character and insert a space?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind counting spaces you can do `d3t` + space.

Another alternative is to use search, e.g. `d/ }` + enter.

Comment: I like the `d/ }`, I didn't know you could delete as such.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete next 2 words by hitting <kbd>2de</kbd> (or <kbd>2dE</kbd>).

- `d` delete
- `e` - forward to the end of word
- `2` - twice

Comment: `2dE` works great. Better than `2dW` which gobbles up the space I want to leave.